# If statement to add column to pandas dataframe gives the same values

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I want to add a new column called I have a pandas dataframe called `week5_233C`. My Python version is 3.19.13.

I wrote an if-statement to add a new column to my data set: `Spike`. If the value in `Value [pV]` is not equal to 0, I want to add a 1 to that row. If `Value [pV]` is 0, then I want to add in the `spike` column that it is 0.

The data looks like this:

```
  TimeStamp [µs]  Value [pV]  
0        1906200         0   
1        1906300         0  
2        1906400         0     
3        1906500    -149012   
4        1906600    -149012
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
  TimeStamp [µs]  Value [pV]  Spike
0        1906200         0      0
1        1906300         0      0
2        1906400         0      0
3        1906500    -149012     1
4        1906600    -149012     1
```

I tried:

```py
week5_233C.loc[week5_233C[' Value [pV]'] != 0, 'Spike'] = 1 
week5_233C.loc[week5_233C[' Value [pV]'] == 0, 'Spike'] = 0
```

but all rows in column `Spike` get the same value.

I also tried:

```py
week5_233C['Spike'] = week5_233C[' Value [pV]'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 0 else 1)
```

Again, it just adds only 0s or only 1s, but does not work with `if` and `else`. See example data:

```
  TimeStamp [µs]  Value [pV]  Spike
0        1906200         0      1
1        1906300         0      1
2        1906400         0      1
3        1906500    -149012     1
4        1906600    -149012     1
```

Doing it like this:

```py
for i in week5_233C[' Value [pV]']:
    if i != 0: 
        week5_233C['Spike'] = 1
    elif i == 0:
        week5_233C['Spike'] = 0
```

does not do anything: does not add a column, does not give an error, and makes Python crash.

However, when I run this if-statement with just a print as such:

```py
for i in week5_233C[' Value [pV]']:
    if i != 0: 
        print(1)
    elif i == 0:
        print(0)
```

then it does print the exact values I want. I cannot figure out how to save these values in a new column.

This:

```py
for i in week5_233C[' Value [pV]']:
    if i != 0:
       week5_233C.concat([1, df.iloc['Spike']]) 
    elif i == 0:
        week5_233C.concat([0, df.iloc['Spike']])
```

gives me an error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'concat'`

How can I make a new column `Spike` and add the values 0 and 1 based on the value in  column `Value [pV]`?

Comment: `week5_233C['Spike'] = week5_233C[' Value [pV]'].ne(0).astype(int)`

Comment: Then I again get only 1s in the 'Spike' column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should check the dtype of `Value [pV]` column. You probably have string that's why you have the same value. Try `print(df['Value [pV]'].dtype)`. If `object` try to convert with `astype(float)` or `pd.to_numeric(df['Value [pV]'])`.

You can also try:

```
df['spike'] = np.where(df['Value [pV]'] == '0', 0, 1)
```

**Update**

To show bad rows and debug your datafame, use the following code:

```
df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df['Value [pV]'], errors='coerce').isna(), 'Value [pV]']
```

Comment: Ah! Its indeed an object! Omg thank you so much. When I do ```pd.to_numeric(df['Value [pV]'])``` I get the following error: ```ValueError: Unable to parse string " Value [pV]" at position 2201```, know any fix for this?

Comment: And indeed when I put the 0 between apostrophes (so like a string) it works too! thanks alot!

Comment: I get this out: ```2201        Value [pV]
5395        Value [pV]
5396        Value [pV]
8280        Value [pV]
13551       Value [pV]
    
1591871     Value [pV]
1599095     Value [pV]
1615340     Value [pV]
1618534     Value [pV]
1619496     Value [pV] ``` and when i check the dtype it is still an object. When i check the values with ```print(week5_233C[' Value [pV]'])``` it does still have its original values ...

Comment: Do you load your data from a file?

Comment: Yes i do. Originally its a .csv

Comment: This csv is probably a concatenation of multiple dataframes with header duplicates. You have to clean it

Comment: Aahhh I see. Yes thats true! You are a hero. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'TimeStamp [µs]':[1906200, 1906300, 1906400, 1906500, 1906600],
                   'Value [pV] ':[0, 0, 0, -149012, -149012],
                   })



df['Spike'] = df.agg({'Value [pV] ': lambda v: int(bool(v))})

print(df)
```

```
   TimeStamp [µs]  Value [pV]   Spike
0         1906200            0      0
1         1906300            0      0
2         1906400            0      0
3         1906500      -149012      1
4         1906600      -149012      1
```

Comment: This somehow also gives me the same values in the column spike: only 1s

Comment: This is not what you are looking for ?

Comment: In your example ``` ['Spike'] = 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 ```  is how I want it. But I kept getting ```[Spike] = 1, 1, 1, 1, 1``` But it turns out it was because 'Value [pV]' was coded as a string instead of a float!